Sent Bonk through the Solana network to my cold wallet
The other day, I bought Bonk coins on Uplink.  I currently use a Tangem cold wallet.  Any time I buy crypto, I get it to my cold wallet as fast as I can.  When listing Bonk in my Tangem wallet, it has to be listed under another network.  I chose listing it under Solana.  While under Solana, you can still click on Bonk and send it through the Bonk network.
After buying the Bonk on Uplink, I sent it to my cold wallet, but accidentally sent it through the Solana network.  Now, I feel like my Bonk tokens are somewhere on the Solana blockchain and never made it to my wallet.  I understand that if I would have sent it through the Bonk network, everything would have been fine.  However, I LEARNED this lesson after the fact.  Is there anyway I can retrieve my Bonk tokens off the blockchain?  I feel like they are there and are basically homeless and stuck.  LoL I sent them to the wrong place.  Are they gone forever?  Anyone have any advice how to retrieve them IF I can?
